# collapsible div with checkbox in header, Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="questionsPage" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Questions</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<div id="questions_list" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="d" data-inset="false"></div>
</div>

</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/questions_list.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is question_list.js:

```
$('#questionsPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'api/questions.json?id=' + id, function(data) {
        questions = data;
        $.each(questions, function(index, question) {
            $('#questions_list').append('<div data-role="collapsible" id="section_' + question.id + '">' +
                                        '<h2>' + question.question + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_' + question.id + '" /></h2>' +
                                        '<p>test</p></div>');
            $('#section_' + question.id).collapsible();
        });
    });
});

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Well, i can see the divs with the checkbox.
But when i click on the checkbox, the div is collapsed and the checkbox is not being checked.

What i am trying to is, when i click on the checkbox, it would be checked.
And when i click anywhere else, only the div would collapse without the checkbox being checked.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm looking over your code now, and so far, I can't say I can quite figure out your solution, however, I can say, I have a plugin that will help you with that nasty little url function. [See Here](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-myurl-extension-how-to-get-that.html)

Comment: Without an example, Kinda need a better explination of your problem, I'm not quite seeing the issue?

Comment: Don't reference to the code,
The script adds collapsible divs into collapsible-set via ajax.
And next to the collapsible title, i want to add a checkbox so when i click on this checkbox, it would be checked without the div collapse

Comment: Oh in that case, you'll need to add a click event to the checkbox that uses jQuery's [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)! This will prevent click events from bubbling up from the checkbox

Comment: Can you please write an example for me? i'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after:

```
$('#questions_list').append('<div data-role="collapsible" id="section_' + question.id + '">' +
                                        '<h2>' + question.question + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_' + question.id + '" /></h2>' +
                                        '<p>test</p></div>');
```

Insert:

```
//  This will simply stop the check box from allowing its parent to be clicked (collapsed) while the checkbox itself is clicked
//  I havn't tested, but should work
$('#checkbox_' + question.id).on("click", function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Well man i have an error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: lol, np, if u dont have .on, you must be running older version?